# Wont insert into database( comment on a comment)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-into

What I'm trying to do here is 
comment on a comment, like Facebookm but it wont insert, and it's not getting c_id & mem_id.

It needs to get the [c_id from blog] and [mem_id from blog_users] then INSERT INTO blog_subcomments.

I just want to know why it's not inserting.

```
if (isset($_POST['s_comment'])&&
  isset($date))
{
$s_comment = get_post('s_comment');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$date = date('d/m/Y h:ia');
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_subcomments (sub_id,s_comment,user_id,comment_id)SELECT c_id,mem_id FROM blog,blog_users VALUES" .
"('','$s_comment','mem_id','c_id','$date')";
if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" .
mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Table structure

blog (this table is all the main comments)
 Author  |  Date  | Comment  |  email | c_id

blog_subcomments(this table is the where you comment on a comment(blog))
sub_id | s_comment | user_id |  comment_id |date_commented

blog_users(this is where all the users data)
 mem_id     name    email   pw

Comment: "Won't insert" is not a diagnostic error we can help you with. You're using the deprecated `mysql_query` interface which is only going to lead you to a whole world of trouble. You should really be using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) instead of just smashing out 1990s style PHP code like this and hoping it works. It's also worth noting that MySQL's `INSERT` does not work the way you have it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the parameter you are passing doesn't match

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_subcomments (sub_id,s_comment,user_id,comment_id)SELECT c_id,mem_id FROM blog,blog_users VALUES" ."('','$s_comment','mem_id','c_id','$date')";
```

the field names provided doesn't have the date and while field values does have a date. so we have 2 work arounds

**1.**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_subcomments (sub_id,s_comment,user_id,comment_id,<date_field_name>)SELECT c_id,mem_id FROM blog,blog_users VALUES" ."('','$s_comment','mem_id','c_id','$date')";
```

**2.**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_subcomments (sub_id,s_comment,user_id,comment_id)SELECT c_id,mem_id FROM blog,blog_users VALUES" ."('','$s_comment','mem_id','c_id')";
```

Comment: yes u r correct @serakfalcon but its optional. I run it like this and it gives result

Comment: yes I noted and deleted my comment. it still makes me cringe.